# How to return the index of the first non-negative list in a list of lists in Python?

Tags: python

The desired output is the index of the first non-negative list.

Say I nested list of numbers like below. I am trying to figure out how to remove the values of the negative lists or just return the index where all the values in the list are positive.

My idea was to enumerate or loop a function that checks if a list has a negative value then pop or remove from the list of lists

Or do I use a list comprehension?

```
# pseudocode
x = [[-1, -2, -1], [-1, -3, -1], [1, 2, 2]]
index_x = [x.index(non_negative(x)) for x in data]
print(index_x)
# 2
```

Comment: the index of the first non-negative list

Comment: Do you have also a mixture of positive and negative values in a given sublist?

Comment: The occurrence of the mixture didn't come up in my situation, but it is possible that I would have to take note of.

Comment: If there are no mixtures, then you can do `index_x = [i for i, j in enumerate(x) if sum(j)>0]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `next` with a generator expression and `enumerate` + `all`. Your logic is equivalent to finding the index of the first sublist containing all non-negative values.

```
x = [[-1, -2, -1], [-1, -3, -1], [1, 2, 2]]

res = next((idx for idx, sub in enumerate(x) if all(i >= 0 for i in sub)), None)

# 2
```

A list comprehension is only useful if you wish to extract indices for *all* sublists matching a condition. The built-in `next` function retrieves the first value from an iterable. If no sublist is found, the specified `None` will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something like this? Just iterate through the lists.

```
from functools import reduce

x = [[-1, -2, -1], [-1, -3, -1], [1, 2, 2]]

for index, sublist in enumerate(x):
    if reduce(lambda a, b: a >= 0 and b >= 0, sublist):
        print(index)
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

For this I'd just use a function with an early return, which I feel makes the intent of "stop looking when you find this" clearer:

```
def first_non_negative(lsts):
    for idx, lst in enumerate(lsts):
        if all(it > 0 for it in lst): 
            return idx
```